# DateTimeField received a naive datetime with no explanantion

Tags: django, python-2.7, datetime

I am going crazy with this warning.

I am working on Django and there's this little problem which is causing me trouble. This view worked before but suddenlt it stopped working and a naive datetime warning showed up. In the command line it iterates over and over like the next image shows and the content isn't shown:
[Command Line Output for Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdM45.png)

The views is as follows:

```
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def loggedin(request):
    data = []
    data2 = []
    data3 = []
    dicdata2 = {}
    dicdata3 = {}
    datainterior = []
    today = timezone.localtime(timezone.now()+timedelta(hours=1)).date()
    tomorrow = today + timedelta(1)
    semana= today - timedelta(7)
    today = today - timedelta(1)
    semana_start = datetime.combine(today, time())
    today_start = datetime.combine(today, time())
    today_end = datetime.combine(tomorrow, time())
    for modulo in Repository.objects.values("des_especialidade").distinct():
        dic = {}
        mod = str(modulo['des_especialidade'])
        dic["label"] = str(mod)
        dic["value"] = Repository.objects.filter(des_especialidade__iexact=mod).count()
        data.append(dic)
    for modulo in Repository.objects.values("modulo").distinct():
        dic = {}
        mod = str(modulo['modulo'])
        dic["label"] = str(mod)
        dic["value"] = Repository.objects.filter(modulo__iexact=mod, dt_diag__gte=semana_start).count()
        datainterior.append(dic)
        # print mod, Repository.objects.filter(modulo__iexact=mod).count()
        # data[mod] = Repository.objects.filter(modulo__iexact=mod).count()
    dicdata2['values'] = datainterior
    dicdata2['key'] = "Cumulative Return"
    dicdata3['values'] = data
    dicdata3['color'] = "#d67777"
    dicdata3['key'] = "Diagnosticos Identificados"
    data3.append(dicdata3)
    data2.append(dicdata2)


#-------sunburst
databurst = []
dictburst = {}
dictburst['name'] = "CHP"
childrenmodulo = []
for modulo in Repository.objects.values("modulo").distinct():
    childrenmodulodic = {}
    mod = str(modulo['modulo'])
    childrenmodulodic['name'] = mod
    childrenesp = []
    for especialidade in Repository.objects.filter(modulo__iexact=mod).values("des_especialidade").distinct():
        childrenespdic = {}
        esp = str(especialidade['des_especialidade'])
        childrenespdic['name'] = esp
        childrencode = []
        for code in Repository.objects.filter(modulo__iexact=mod,des_especialidade__iexact=esp).values("cod_diagnosis").distinct():
            childrencodedic = {}
            codee= str(code['cod_diagnosis'])
            childrencodedic['name'] = 'ICD9 - '+codee
            childrencodedic['size'] = Repository.objects.filter(modulo__iexact=mod,des_especialidade__iexact=esp,cod_diagnosis__iexact=codee).count()
            childrencode.append(childrencodedic)
        childrenespdic['children'] = childrencode



        #childrenespdic['size'] = Repository.objects.filter(des_especialidade__iexact=esp).count()
        childrenesp.append(childrenespdic)
    childrenmodulodic['children'] = childrenesp
    childrenmodulo.append(childrenmodulodic)
dictburst['children'] = childrenmodulo
databurst.append(dictburst)
# print databurst



# --------stacked area chart
datastack = []
for modulo in Repository.objects.values("modulo").distinct():
    datastackdic = {}
    mod = str(modulo['modulo'])
    datastackdic['key'] = mod
    monthsarray = []
    year = timezone.localtime(timezone.now()+timedelta(hours=1)).year
    month = timezone.localtime(timezone.now()+timedelta(hours=1)).month
    last = timezone.localtime(timezone.now()+timedelta(hours=1)) - relativedelta(years=1)
    lastyear = int(last.year)
    lastmonth = int(last.month)
    #i = 1
    while lastmonth <= int(month) or lastyear<int(year):
        date = str(lastmonth) + '/' + str(lastyear)
        if (lastmonth < 12):
            datef = str(lastmonth + 1) + '/' + str(lastyear)
        else:
            lastmonth = 01
            lastyear = int(lastyear)+1
            datef = str(lastmonth)+'/'+ str(lastyear)
            lastmonth = 0
        datainicial = datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%Y')
        datafinal = datetime.strptime(datef, '%m/%Y')
        #print "lastmonth",lastmonth,"lastyear", lastyear
        #print "datainicial:",datainicial,"datafinal: ",datafinal
        filtro = Repository.objects.filter(modulo__iexact=mod)
        count = filtro.filter(dt_diag__gte=datainicial, dt_diag__lt=datafinal).count()
        conv = datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%Y')
        ms = datetime_to_ms_str(conv)
        monthsarray.append([ms, count])
        #i += 1
        lastmonth += 1
    datastackdic['values'] = monthsarray
    datastack.append(datastackdic)
    #print datastack


if request.user.last_login is not None:
    #print(request.user.last_login)
    contador_novas = Repository.objects.filter(dt_diag__lte=today_end, dt_diag__gte=today_start).count()
return render_to_response('loggedin.html',
                          {'user': request.user.username, 'contador': contador_novas, 'data': data, 'data2': data2,
                           'data3': data3,
                           'databurst': databurst, 'datastack':datastack})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your statements like:

```
datainicial = datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%Y')
```

are creating native python time without timezone support. When you apply queries or assignment on those variables to the django date fields, it's going to give you the warnings. You have to make them all timezone aware in order to suppress the warnings.

An easy fix would be:

```
from django.utils import timezone

datainicial = datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%Y')
datainicial = timezone.make_aware(datainicial, timezone.utc)
```

Comment: This work was done by a colleague of mine. I am continuing his work. Any idea how can I solve that situation?

Comment: I edited my answer. You need to find all places where native time is used to do that.

Comment: Now, I see no error but the page loads for a long time and then I get
"OverflowError at /OrganApp/dash/
mktime argument out of range".

I'd say it comes from this function which is going through months (I guess).

def datetime_to_ms_str(dt):
    return str(1000 * mktime(dt.timetuple()))

Comment: You shouldn't do the timezone aware conversion to `conv`. It's not directly applied to your django queries, so the timezone doesn't matter for that one. In general, you should only apply the conversion to those datetime objects that are in your queries like `dt_diag__gte=datainicial, dt_diag__lt=datafinal`.

Comment: I didn't make `conv` timezone aware and the same error "mktime argument out of range" appears.  
Do you know why?
And by the way, I am very thankful for your help.

Comment: Sorry, without the context of your code I cannot guess what triggers that error and it's kind of off topic of your current question. I suggest you closing this thread by checking it and open another topic. It will make your question more explicit/obvious and other people can benefit from it.